# Setting default argument for an extended class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments, design-patterns

I am making an application that involves create/retrieve/update/delete operations.

So for the add and edit method I want to re-use core components that are the same in both functions. So I made a shared abstract class and then my add and edit classes extend the shared so they each have the same core but can still have differences.

I instantiate these objects/Fragments by using the newInstance method, which is where I usually pass in arguments, set them into the Bundle, and then read them back in the onCreateView methods.

However I need to be able to pull in arguments to the shared class, but I can't because it's abstract, and when I instantiate the objects, I am instantiating Edit and Add objects, which means only the child classes can have arguments.

What's the accepted practice for getting around this?

```
public abstract class SharedStuffDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    protected MyObject mMyObject; //I'd like to be able to init. this

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shared_layout, container, false);

        //do a bunch of other stuff here, sharable attributes
        initOtherThings(savedInstanceState);
        return contentView;
    }

    protected abstract void initOtherThings(Bundle savedInstanceState);


}
```

And then for example, the add class:

```
public class AddDialogFragment extends SharedStuffDialogFragment {
    private static final String ARGUMENT_OBJECT = "argument_object";
    private MyObject mMyObject;

    public static AddDialogFragment newInstance(MyObject object) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARGUMENT_OBJECT, object); //would really rather set this to shared
        AddDialogFragment fragment = new AddDialogFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initOtherThings(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mMyObject = getArguments().getParcelable(ARGUMENT_OBJECT);
        //do stuff unique to add operations
    }

}
```

Comment: Why on earth did someone downvote this? It's a perfectly reasonable qusetion

Comment: You can have a field in your base class which is abstract. When you pass argument to create sub class instances, set the value to the common field in the base class. That way you can use the arguments being passed

Comment: How do I do that properly when the newInstance methods are all about settings arguments for the child fragments?

Comment: Inside your new instance method, just do "this.mMyObject = object"

Comment: I don't think that's right, it violates factory method and I think "super" might make more sense than "this"

Comment: Sorry not "this". I meant fragment.setMyObject

Comment: Or another was is to create a constructor for your add class which accepts myobject. And inside that do this.myobject = object

Comment: You're not supposed to make argument constructors for fragments, hence the factory method

Comment: Changed tags for clarity

Comment: Is it necessary to do this structure in the fragment classes?  Maybe it would be simpler to move the non-UI parts to separate classes.  Then you can have whatever class structure you want, and use the appropriate child class from the fragment.